# Unable to blink led 3 times in Arduino program

Tags: c, loops, arduino

I want to run the loop for three times to blink the led 3 times in Arduino program. How to run the loop for 3 times and exit from the loop.how to use return statement in loop? once led is getting on  for 1 sec and then getting off.

```
int LedPin = 13;
int Loops = 1;
void setup() {

  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
Loops = Loops + 1;
  if    ( Loops < 3 )

  {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(2000);  
    }

 else  {
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);      
  exit(0);  
  }
}
```

Comment: please google for "how to write a loop in c"

Answer (score 0):

The arduino loop loops forever.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Loop

If you want to stop running that loop, you could put the arduino in sleep mode:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode

I also recommend you have a thorough look at how flow control works (and possibly state machines). Have a look at chapter 5. Control Structures:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples

Answer (score 0):

If we "unroll" the `loop` function, we get:

```
// Loops is 1 on the first call.
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
Loops = Loops + 1;
// Loops is now 2
if (Loops < 3)
{
    // So, we enter here...
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(2000);  
}
else
{
    // but not here
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);      
    exit(0);  
}
// Next call:
// Turn off the light.
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
Loops = Loops + 1;
// Loops is now 3
if (Loops < 3)
{
    // So we don't enter here
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(2000);  
}
else
{
    // but we enter here
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);      
    // Which exits
    exit(0);  
}
```

So you turn on the LED once, then turn it off and exit.
If you adjust the loop counter, you will turn off the LED and then immediately turn it on again, which will just look like it's on for a longer period.

You probably want to do a whole on/off cycle on each loop - something like this:

```
int LedPin = 13;
int Loops = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    Loops = Loops + 1;
    if (Loops <= 3)
    {
        digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
        delay(2000);
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.


  for (int i=0; i < 4 ; i++) 
  {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH); 
     delay(1000); 
     digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(1000);    

  }

}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int LedPin = 13;

void setup() {
pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
function() ;       //call this function whatever you want
}

void function()
{
digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
delay(1000)       //add the desired delay
digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
delay(1000)     //add the desired delay
digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
delay(1000)       //add the desired delay
digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
delay(1000)     //add the desired delay
digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
delay(1000)       //add the desired delay
digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
delay(1000)     //add the desired delay

}
```